# Google VM additional disk storage

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I created a VM with Google Compute Engine and I'm running out of space on it, so I created another disk and attached it to the VM through Google Console menu, but when I still login to the VM through SSH it's still showing up the original space of my VM.

The original VM space is 10GB and the disk is 100GB, when I login to console.developers.google.com and click on VM instances I see my VM and under it the "disk" tab for it I see "VM1, disk-1".

Through SSH I still see `Usage of /:   94.8% of 9.81GB`. Do I need to run a command through SSH to make it use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to add another disk to a Google Compute Engine VM:

1. [create a new disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#create_disk)
2. [attach the disk to the VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#attach_disk)
3. [format and mount the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#formatting), e.g.,

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir MOUNT_POINT
   $ sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" \
         DISK_LOCATION MOUNT_POINT
   ```

Looks like you did steps 1 and 2, so you just need to do step 3 to complete the process.